# Workarounds for High Floating-Point Error in NumPy Arrays Raised to Powers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-accuracy, gmpy

I have data that represents responses from a 24(?)-bit A/D converter. I am setting up the data to go into a polynomial regression in the function below, but I am getting detrimental amounts of floating-point error, so much so that it makes the coefficients of my regression completely unusable later.

The data, once normalized, ranges between -1 and 1. I am getting floating-point errors of roughly ~0.15 in terms that go up to the fourth degree. Due to extraneous reasons, I can't lower the degree of the regression terms, but thank you @Robert Dodier for pointing out that this method, in general, gets fairly unstable when higher degrees are added.

Is there a way to reduce the floating-point error? Speed nor memory isn't the chief goal here: the accuracy needs to be close to exact, if possible. The data set is pretty small (~ 400 rows).

I also tried using the gmpy2 library's "mpfr" class, but that didn't seem to make a difference. For completeness, I've included that version, too.

After this function, I simply feed the data into a QR-decomposed regression (see below).

After processing the data, I also checked if the floating-point error could be attributed to the regression, but when I run an SVD-style regression, I get almost identical coefficients as in the QR-style, so that is not the problem.

Here are those functions:

```py
import numpy as np
def load_data(path):
    data = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=',')

    # Features
    A = data[:, 1:3]

    # Normalize the data
    A /= (2 ** 24)

    # Extract columns P and T
    P = A[:, 0]
    T = A[:, 1]

    # Compute new columns based on P and T
    col_ones = np.ones_like(P, dtype=float)
    T2 = T ** 2
    T3 = T ** 3
    PT = P * T
    PT2 = P * (T ** 2)

    # ... continue making features

    # Combine the new columns into a new array
    A = np.column_stack((col_ones, T, T2, T3, P, PT, PT2)) # ... add higher degree features
    b = data[:, 0]  # ref

    return A, b
```

```py
import gmpy2
from gmpy2 import mpfr
def load_data_gmpy(path):
    data = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=',', skiprows=15)

    # Features
    b = data[:, 0]  # ref
    P = data[:, 1]
    T = data[:, 2]

    gmpy2.set_context(gmpy2.context())
    with gmpy2.local_context() as ctx:
        ctx.precision = 2000

        # Normalize the data
        P = [mpfr(p) / (2 ** 24) for p in P]
        T = [mpfr(t) / (2 ** 24) for t in T]

        # Compute new columns based on P and T
        col1 = np.ones_like(P, dtype=float)
        T2 =   np.array([float(t ** 2) for t in T])
        T3 =   np.array([float(t ** 3) for t in T])
        PT =   np.array([float(p * t) for p, t in zip(P, T)])
        PT2 =  np.array([float(p * (t ** 2)) for p, t in zip(P, T)])
        # ... continue making features

        # Convert the results back to numpy arrays
        # add higher-degree features here...
        A = np.column_stack((col1, np.array(T, dtype=float), T2, T3, np.array(P, dtype=float), PT, PT2)) 

        return A, b
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the other code I'm using:

```py
def do_qr_regression(X, y):
    # QR decomposition
    Q, R = np.linalg.qr(X)
    beta = np.linalg.inv(R).dot(Q.T).dot(y)

    # predict using coefficients
    yhat = X.dot(beta)

    return beta, yhat


def do_svd_regression(X, y):
    # calculate coefficients

    beta = np.linalg.pinv(X).dot(y)
    # predict using coefficients
    yhat = X.dot(beta)

    return beta, yhat


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data, ref = load_data("path\to\file.txt")

    coefs_qr, values = do_qr_regression(data, ref)
    residuals_qr: np.array = values - ref

    coefs_svd, values = do_svd_regression(data, ref)
    residuals_svd: np.array = values - ref

    plt.plot(residuals_qr, 'r-', label='QR')
    plt.plot(residuals_svd, 'g-', label='SVD')

    plt.xlabel('Index')
    plt.ylabel('Residuals')  
    plt.title('Comparison of Residuals')

    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

    coefs_qr = np.array(coefs_qr)
    coefs_svd = np.array(coefs_svd)

    # Combine the coefficients into a single array for easier handling
    coefficients = np.column_stack((coefs_qr, coefs_svd))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Hide the axes
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')

    table = ax.table(cellText=coefficients, colLabels=['QR', 'SVD'], loc='center')

    plt.show()
```

Here is the data I'm working with, comma-separated:

```
-3.79209332168102E-02,7099245.9,7858558.6,0
-1.70869659632444E-02,7100756.73333333,7871731.93333333,0
2.81271850690246E-03,7102327.96666667,7884444.56666667,0
9.36040934175253E-03,7103800.66666667,7895645.66666667,0
-2.79413126409054E-02,7105061.4,7904756.23333333,0
-8.74655845109373E-04,7106050,7911871.56666667,0
6.24037310481071E-02,7106884.86666667,7916973.93333333,0
-2.94671542942524E-02,7107334.73333333,7920926.13333333,0
-3.12367863953114E-02,7107785.43333333,7923975.76666667,0
-1.45234884694219E-02,7108178.7,7926395.46666667,0
-1.92804485559464E-02,7108474,7928171.03333333,0
-4.53804135322571E-02,7108595.13333333,7929486.1,0
-5.98167441785336E-03,7108821.33333333,7930345.16666667,0
1.31415268406272E-02,7108845.83333333,7931080.26666667,0
2.4978460278362E-03,7108934.23333333,7931916.93333333,0
2.45027570053935E-03,7109045.6,7932515.3,0
9.87916067242622E-03,7109136.06666667,7932965.66666667,0
4.31683212518692E-02,7109269.63333333,7933144.7,0
2.00799219310284E-02,7109163.5,7933265.43333333,0
-1.38221913948655E-02,7109125.3,7933400.83333333,0
6.25846162438393E-02,7109318.86666667,7933660.8,0
3.29688005149364E-02,7109344.7,7933879.2,0
-0.049491997808218,7109224.43333333,7934110.6,0
5.38606084883213E-02,7109377.9,7934038.76666667,0
0.046255461871624,7109361.93333333,7933981.06666667,0
-2.44040284305811E-02,7109167,7934010.16666667,0
-3.04582342505455E-03,7109178.06666667,7934082.06666667,0
-2.04245466738939E-02,7109236.86666667,7934336.33333333,0
3.32059040665627E-02,7109441.43333333,7934345.6,0
9.03827371075749E-04,7109281.06666667,7934420.7,0
-3499.73901367188,1202227.26666667,7934381.06666667,0
-2799.94750976563,2304463.93333333,7934337.03333333,0
-2100.15991210938,3449484.63333333,7934287.53333333,0
-1400.3271484375,4635445.83333333,7934274.23333333,0
-699.855041503906,5858549,7934317.1,0
-1.61615032702684E-02,7109198.86666667,7934278.73333333,0
699.784729003906,8378929.6,7934309.36666667,0
1400.33154296875,9658856.5,7934361.6,0
2100.10986328125,10935471.5666667,7934317.63333333,0
2799.98217773438,12201155.9333333,7934394.7,0
3499.77807617188,13448160.3333333,7934492.96666667,0
2100.14331054688,10935360.0666667,7934492,0
699.819885253906,8379085,7934628.4,0
-699.844909667969,5858840.93333333,7934707.96666667,0
-2100.10327148438,3450137.6,7934749.63333333,0
-3499.79321289063,1202676.8,7934767.03333333,0
8.03543347865343E-03,7109186.6,7934803.13333333,0
-9.97814815491438E-03,7109341.6,7934805.36666667,0
1.38494540005922E-02,7109324.26666667,7934681.5,0
-9.96059738099575E-03,7109348.36666667,7934635.8,0
-1.35194389149547E-02,7109378.2,7934483.73333333,0
-3.13356779515743E-02,7109289.9,7934504.9,0
-4.50224168598652E-02,7109315.33333333,7934413.96666667,0
6.23549288138747E-03,7109341.03333333,7934317.83333333,0
-3.34550850093365E-02,7108801.1,7929951.3,0
1.12465918064117E-02,7107938,7920887.5,0
-1.28802107647061E-02,7106526.06666667,7910323.06666667,0
-0.039332490414381,7105237.73333333,7900160.56666667,0
-0.043127778917551,7104207.3,7891344.73333333,0
-1.92340034991503E-02,7103242.8,7884079.7,0
-4.84014675021172E-02,7102440.16666667,7878276.76666667,0
-4.76139895617962E-02,7101828.73333333,7873784.73333333,0
3.18983495235443E-02,7101437.2,7870437.93333333,0
9.64516401290894E-02,7101117.96666667,7867993.23333333,0
8.89699254184961E-03,7100847.33333333,7866227.33333333,0
-3.06270942091942E-02,7100583.8,7864736,0
5.08495047688484E-03,7100603.36666667,7863470.23333333,0
-0.010664333589375,7100353.5,7862663.23333333,0
2.65998281538486E-02,7100255.1,7862184.06666667,0
6.04479247704148E-03,7100135.13333333,7862000.73333333,0
-1.09656411223114E-03,7100172.4,7861730.8,0
-4.44185733795166E-03,7100128.23333333,7861559.9,0
-4.51760971918702E-03,7099993.9,7861277,0
-1.36335138231516E-02,7100083.4,7861058.4,0
-2.23144199699163E-02,7100031,7861020.8,0
-2.40478087216616E-02,7100023.73333333,7861114.53333333,0
0.022402485832572,7100087.36666667,7861231.93333333,0
-4.91335950791836E-02,7099976.53333333,7861280.7,0
-5.69252856075764E-03,7100084.96666667,7861182.93333333,0
-4.99452725052834E-02,7099891.23333333,7861115.36666667,0
3.33451516926289E-02,7100095.53333333,7861021.03333333,0
1.38003788888454E-02,7100033.56666667,7861150.43333333,0
2.38548628985882E-02,7100072.3,7861265.3,0
-4.68269409611821E-03,7100125.73333333,7861413.7,0
-3499.7578125,1123048.16666667,7861512.4,0
-2799.97534179688,2238191.83333333,7861524.56666667,0
-2100.11962890625,3397073.1,7861466.73333333,0
-1400.32946777344,4596996.43333333,7861535.36666667,0
-699.830017089844,5834631.26666667,7861499.76666667,0
-1.43672842532396E-02,7100015.03333333,7861518.9,0
699.810241699219,8384897.4,7861349.3,0
1400.34008789063,9679774.6,7861376.6,0
2100.12841796875,10971193.2666667,7861391.83333333,0
2799.93481445313,12251729.0333333,7861329.36666667,0
3499.79321289063,13513466.1666667,7861291.8,0
2100.072265625,10971180.2333333,7861337.43333333,0
699.802185058594,8384749.86666667,7861384.66666667,0
-699.831359863281,5834669.86666667,7861344.13333333,0
-2100.1416015625,3397190.4,7861383.76666667,0
-3499.73583984375,1122820.1,7861450.23333333,0
-1.53773836791515E-02,7099952.66666667,7861562.16666667,0
2.16550659388304E-02,7100005.5,7861625.33333333,0
1.52593497186899E-02,7100141,7861707.73333333,0
5.74888987466693E-03,7100072.46666667,7861745.36666667,0
-4.55636046826839E-02,7100108.8,7861690.1,0
2.12178695946932E-02,7100126.8,7861712.5,0
8.85779663803987E-05,7100150.3,7861695.1,0
3.49641516804695E-02,7100172.93333333,7861648.96666667,0
2.02182307839394E-02,7099726.8,7857342.46666667,0
4.49221767485142E-02,7098711.5,7848147.13333333,0
-8.8534401729703E-03,7097407.46666667,7837623.96666667,0
3.99499833583832E-02,7096186.56666667,7827610.93333333,0
-2.05677356570959E-02,7095130.56666667,7819117.36666667,0
-1.31802512332797E-02,7094238.83333333,7812281.93333333,0
-1.42691014334559E-02,7093479.46666667,7806904.6,0
-0.012847593985498,7092893.4,7802742.43333333,0
-2.66020242124796E-02,7092492.5,7799630.43333333,0
-0.018302321434021,7092206.46666667,7797321.86666667,0
5.29859401285648E-02,7092082.1,7795496.43333333,0
7.84578826278448E-03,7091791.5,7794286.1,0
-5.35906804725528E-03,7091603.5,7793303.96666667,0
-2.07541678100824E-02,7091501.26666667,7792598.83333333,0
1.80722959339619E-02,7091396.2,7791806.6,0
-3.94488051533699E-02,7091242.73333333,7791149.7,0
3.63344862125814E-03,7091250.63333333,7790762.53333333,0
-4.55112680792809E-02,7091237.03333333,7790489.26666667,0
-2.56204847246408E-02,7091167.66666667,7790459.83333333,0
-6.77033793181181E-03,7091144.66666667,7790522.96666667,0
-1.52006316930056E-02,7091146.06666667,7790626.46666667,0
-1.74931231886148E-02,7091231.06666667,7790489.6,0
3.04559525102377E-02,7091258.33333333,7790312.63333333,0
1.87910366803408E-02,7091165.03333333,7790190.86666667,0
-2.39088479429483E-02,7091008.23333333,7790078,0
6.64425388094969E-05,7091084.43333333,7790061.56666667,0
-2.25651804357767E-02,7091043.03333333,7790273.06666667,0
2.07707360386848E-02,7091126.56666667,7790437.6,0
2.37347651273012E-02,7091263.5,7790441.1,0
-5.41624277830124E-02,7091120.63333333,7790323.3,0
-3499.80859375,1044735.63333333,7790352.43333333,0
-2800.00073242188,2172890.5,7790237.03333333,0
-2100.14575195313,3345007.56666667,7790201.13333333,0
-1400.36584472656,4558900.56666667,7790226.4,0
-699.809997558594,5810935.03333333,7790239.93333333,0
4.18546199798584E-02,7091075.83333333,7790161.23333333,0
699.776672363281,8390556.96666667,7790070.46666667,0
1400.3115234375,9700408.83333333,7790018.73333333,0
2100.16650390625,11006604.2,7790171.36666667,0
2799.94165039063,12301380.2,7790211.56666667,0
3499.7763671875,13577070.8,7790279.46666667,0
2100.16162109375,11006471.9333333,7790350.63333333,0
699.780151367188,8390505.33333333,7790456,0
-699.810913085938,5811202.36666667,7790453.13333333,0
-2100.10302734375,3345652.06666667,7790539.86666667,0
-3499.73876953125,1045294.73333333,7790582.16666667,0
1.73759907484055E-02,7091025.03333333,7790644.8,0
2.01047714799643E-02,7091107.53333333,7790558.2,0
2.24752072244883E-03,7091140.16666667,7790580.2,0
-1.32585959509015E-02,7091096.56666667,7790555.4,0
-7.19826202839613E-03,7091107.06666667,7790543.36666667,0
3.61428130418062E-03,7091133.53333333,7790461.93333333,0
-2.32487842440605E-02,7091052.1,7790335.33333333,0
-5.49840591847897E-02,7091149.4,7790207.7,0
3.98981757462025E-02,7090648.96666667,7785734.23333333,0
1.46631279494613E-03,7089523.6,7776410.16666667,0
-0.034836120903492,7088133.86666667,7765643.56666667,0
-1.33202392607927E-02,7087033.73333333,7755333.3,0
4.77167181670666E-02,7085954.53333333,7746603.5,0
-2.35397387295961E-02,7084947.7,7739336.36666667,0
-1.58618856221437E-02,7084149.43333333,7733360.33333333,0
2.09058001637459E-02,7083611.56666667,7728649.2,0
4.73269168287516E-03,7083061.13333333,7725033.83333333,0
-8.72943364083767E-03,7082670.06666667,7722187.66666667,0
6.07541063800454E-04,7082414.83333333,7720449.5,0
2.11557392030954E-02,7082177.1,7719157.63333333,0
-8.93950648605824E-03,7081983.33333333,7718230.36666667,0
1.48135358467698E-02,7082007.53333333,7717559.86666667,0
-1.74845289438963E-02,7081917.73333333,7716896.56666667,0
-3.58402319252491E-02,7081759.63333333,7716298.53333333,0
-9.83892288058996E-03,7081661.13333333,7715940.8,0
-5.3809960372746E-03,7081551.06666667,7715748.26666667,0
-3.37877981364727E-02,7081636.8,7715558.76666667,0
-3.07282358407974E-02,7081567,7715645.33333333,0
-1.86734683811665E-02,7081683.2,7715833.46666667,0
4.15685400366783E-03,7081710.03333333,7715698.3,0
-4.20616194605827E-02,7081505.43333333,7715539.7,0
-5.11215217411518E-02,7081459.93333333,7715489.3,0
-1.06146400794387E-02,7081480.83333333,7715480.9,0
4.61808376712725E-04,7081543.13333333,7715439.33333333,0
-1.48327779024839E-02,7081488.86666667,7715699.1,0
4.04580915346742E-03,7081575.73333333,7715893.5,0
1.58266047947109E-03,7081648.43333333,7716037.63333333,0
-1.35219632647932E-03,7081690.16666667,7715966.86666667,0
-3499.7919921875,962689.433333333,7716014.93333333,0
-2799.97314453125,2104150.43333333,7715927.1,0
-2100.17724609375,3290496.3,7715859.6,0
-1400.34716796875,4519015.36666667,7715808.83333333,0
-699.774841308594,5786147.43333333,7715839.83333333,0
-5.68454014137387E-03,7081484.03333333,7715817.6,0
699.842895507813,8396739.46666667,7715818.8,0
1400.36413574219,9722084.36666667,7715858.53333333,0
2100.17211914063,11043774.1333333,7715881.66666667,0
2799.99145507813,12353820.6,7715903.03333333,0
3499.73315429688,13644476,7715889.2,0
2100.158203125,11043704.0333333,7715882.53333333,0
699.841979980469,8396717.2,7715932.06666667,0
-699.787963867188,5786328.96666667,7715940.26666667,0
-2100.16064453125,3290925.26666667,7716020.4,0
-3499.77075195313,962726.9,7715981.1,0
-2.16855364851654E-03,7081460.93333333,7716077.46666667,0
3.91276776790619E-02,7081648.6,7716030.43333333,0
1.10400456469506E-03,7081471.23333333,7716112.13333333,0
-1.04349572211504E-02,7081666,7716014.43333333,0
0.018389604985714,7081695.36666667,7715970.26666667,0
1.04607185348868E-02,7081480.43333333,7715969.53333333,0
-3.41426394879818E-02,7081491.5,7715824.03333333,0
3.98268969729543E-03,7081678.86666667,7715708.9,0
4.61700260639191E-02,7082303.46666667,7735863,0
9.88708143268013E-06,7086371.1,7778853.1,0
-2.10136622190475E-02,7091733.53333333,7823589.7,0
-8.28896164894104E-02,7097000.16666667,7863218.13333333,0
-2.90316268801689E-02,7101574.23333333,7895984.76666667,0
-4.51886840164661E-02,7105412.4,7922301.46666667,0
-8.85282643139362E-03,7108472,7942881.2,0
8.17723281215876E-04,7110800.96666667,7958968.36666667,0
-3.56500074267387E-02,7112605.33333333,7971182.8,0
-2.40123625844717E-02,7114010.03333333,7980626.06666667,0
2.13804934173822E-02,7115218.66666667,7987816.93333333,0
3.75584177672863E-02,7116124.36666667,7993192.8,0
-1.80327799171209E-02,7116639.7,7996903.86666667,0
-2.38293204456568E-02,7117014.23333333,7999355.96666667,0
-1.09991738572717E-02,7117254.53333333,8001154.3,0
5.18193654716015E-03,7117444.13333333,8002569.36666667,0
-3.07104792445898E-02,7117692.33333333,8003610.36666667,0
3.38072143495083E-02,7117916.43333333,8004628.83333333,0
-1.69666297733784E-02,7117918,8005442.33333333,0
1.77701096981764E-03,7118039.16666667,8005927.16666667,0
5.37889217957854E-03,7118148.2,8006099.16666667,0
-1.92022491246462E-02,7118113.26666667,8006286.3,0
-9.50242951512337E-03,7118129.76666667,8006489.56666667,0
1.36461891233921E-02,7118214.9,8006677.13333333,0
-1.52958864346147E-02,7118143.03333333,8006937.4,0
-3.89085412025452E-02,7118193.03333333,8007191,0
-2.84714680165052E-02,7118230.73333333,8007397.73333333,0
-1.43435895442963E-02,7118243.2,8007497,0
-5.30800186097622E-02,7118305.6,8007391.06666667,0
2.48046685010195E-02,7118336.5,8007365.66666667,0
-6.10402273014188E-03,7118275.06666667,8007229.2,0
2.57898680865765E-02,7118345.96666667,8007308.26666667,0
-1.62047185003757E-02,7118334.7,8007419.1,0
-4.70929257571697E-02,7118304.26666667,8007538.66666667,0
6.07083551585674E-02,7118504.3,8007508.96666667,0
-5.40002668276429E-03,7118424.6,8007315.56666667,0
3.23888137936592E-02,7118403.33333333,8007244.23333333,0
-3499.79907226563,1280792.03333333,8007201.13333333,0
-2799.90942382813,2369980.83333333,8007228.6,0
-2100.13354492188,3501743.13333333,8007199.8,0
-1400.35778808594,4673710.63333333,8007273.96666667,0
-699.814392089844,5882406.56666667,8007345.6,0
3.67461107671261E-02,7118409.23333333,8007356.33333333,0
699.881713867188,8373388.63333333,8007395.36666667,0
1400.31982421875,9637808.46666667,8007463.36666667,0
2100.09692382813,10899629.9666667,8007490.4,0
2799.95971679688,12150662.8666667,8007532.2,0
3499.82153320313,13383592.0333333,8007588.96666667,0
2100.072265625,10899499.9666667,8007597.8,0
699.8173828125,8373096.33333333,8007601.1,0
-699.840087890625,5882589.8,8007534.7,0
-2100.1220703125,3502230.96666667,8007502.26666667,0
-3499.74658203125,1281037.56666667,8007444.73333333,0
-1.11853713169694E-02,7118179.8,8007418.66666667,0
2.13318057358265E-02,7118354.93333333,8007406.06666667,0
-1.65873449295759E-02,7118301.9,8007329.63333333,0
1.63328442722559E-02,7118304.63333333,8007280.2,0
-4.71936166286469E-02,7118305.53333333,8007227.83333333,0
4.02847342193127E-02,7118463.6,8007213.4,0
-1.44817039836198E-03,7118286.5,8007201.4,0
-5.0851539708674E-03,7118309.53333333,8007205.73333333,0
-3.98449134081602E-04,7118504.9,8011980.13333333,0
-6.03146515786648E-02,7119515.13333333,8021868.36666667,0
-4.03936672955751E-03,7120863.96666667,8032189.9,0
-6.98103802278638E-03,7122073.83333333,8041542.23333333,0
4.83530722558498E-02,7123372.7,8049472.83333333,0
-2.28271950036287E-02,7124021.9,8056005.9,0
2.81748063862324E-02,7124839.2,8061085.23333333,0
1.82347325608134E-03,7125391.5,8064816.86666667,0
-6.12296303734183E-03,7125748.43333333,8067568.3,0
4.73247654736042E-02,7126241.66666667,8069591.7,0
-5.71926683187485E-03,7126280.86666667,8071140.93333333,0
-2.27651512250304E-03,7126484.63333333,8072162.16666667,0
-8.50704964250326E-03,7126569.73333333,8073022.3,0
-5.63930440694094E-03,7126653.03333333,8073734.63333333,0
-2.53348681144416E-03,7126804.23333333,8074387.53333333,0
3.93001642078161E-03,7126859.56666667,8074948.43333333,0
1.09315607696772E-02,7126942.63333333,8075495.23333333,0
-2.10541188716888E-02,7126995.23333333,8075703.5,0
1.45042343065143E-02,7127057.76666667,8075796.8,0
3.60367936082184E-03,7126993.03333333,8075887.36666667,0
-2.91402102448046E-03,7126977.53333333,8075924.86666667,0
-3.79348583519459E-02,7126975.1,8076016.56666667,0
-4.09707948565483E-02,7126975.8,8076238.5,0
-7.12174223735929E-03,7127122.5,8076391.73333333,0
-5.99638512358069E-03,7127117.83333333,8076460.9,0
1.56288663856685E-03,7127184.96666667,8076374.23333333,0
1.09642092138529E-03,7127106.63333333,8076258.16666667,0
0.016278225928545,7127143.06666667,8076284,0
1.83248687535524E-02,7127077.06666667,8076419.66666667,0
-1.65796279907227E-02,7127119.96666667,8076572.66666667,0
-3499.77880859375,1355708.13333333,8076676,0
-2799.95971679688,2432605.1,8076737.76666667,0
-2100.1455078125,3551531.9,8076754.56666667,0
-1400.35522460938,4710194.43333333,8076727.63333333,0
-699.85595703125,5905108.83333333,8076735.8,0
-3.29180955886841E-02,7127131.73333333,8076705,0
699.765197753906,8367857.7,8076656.8,0
1400.35363769531,9618727.36666667,8076612,0
2100.1962890625,10866536.0333333,8076532.16666667,0
2799.95556640625,12103889.5666667,8076466.7,0
3499.74584960938,13323243.8666667,8076399.2,0
2100.10327148438,10866507.7666667,8076403.76666667,0
699.800842285156,8367921.1,8076404,0
-699.841247558594,5905151.16666667,8076431.43333333,0
-2100.15576171875,3551458.73333333,8076400.6,0
-3499.77734375,1355352.33333333,8076425.43333333,0
-5.93360476195812E-02,7126896.36666667,8076473.66666667,0
3.64837385714054E-02,7127127.13333333,8076496.13333333,0
6.18775747716427E-03,7127107.5,8076546.86666667,0
5.72802796959877E-02,7127264.93333333,8076595.46666667,0
1.55833698809147E-02,7127157.3,8076656.36666667,0
3.46873626112938E-02,7127225.46666667,8076730.93333333,0
9.63039509952068E-03,7127202.3,8076771.63333333,0
3.82525869645178E-03,7127286.3,8076864.43333333,0
2.24332846701145E-02,7127459.53333333,8081277.83333333,0
-7.82423280179501E-03,7128421.56666667,8090686.66666667,0
1.48659506812692E-02,7129608.66666667,8100729.5,0
-2.69332826137543E-02,7130733.6,8109870.63333333,0
-0.031025119125843,7131771.46666667,8117673.53333333,0
-2.49610245227814E-02,7132679.4,8124054.16666667,0
5.15121594071388E-02,7133479.76666667,8129157.93333333,0
1.81873627007008E-02,7134086.1,8133071.83333333,0
2.11541038006544E-02,7134474.16666667,8135979.83333333,0
5.75242005288601E-03,7134779.4,8137973.7,0
-4.52917255461216E-02,7134811.33333333,8139276.66666667,0
-4.35533635318279E-02,7134973.93333333,8140199.2,0
-6.00391067564487E-02,7135104.26666667,8140983.86666667,0
-5.12299053370953E-02,7135256.56666667,8141566.93333333,0
2.56956275552511E-02,7135377,8141867.13333333,0
-1.19852740317583E-02,7135357.36666667,8141955.9,0
5.14724873937666E-04,7135521.03333333,8142101.26666667,0
1.36296544224024E-02,7135426.36666667,8142274.26666667,0
-4.29645599797368E-03,7135398.6,8142437.4,0
-2.54887882620096E-02,7135453.1,8142671.2,0
-5.81305585801601E-02,7135371.4,8142723.76666667,0
-1.31594445556402E-02,7135455.06666667,8142622.5,0
4.17865766212344E-03,7135454.16666667,8142527.1,0
-6.31118519231677E-03,7135462.96666667,8142507.2,0
-7.93107785284519E-03,7135447.33333333,8142565.53333333,0
-2.60955952107906E-02,7135595.9,8142635.03333333,0
2.28419457562268E-03,7135472.9,8142639.83333333,0
-1.20748803019524E-02,7135484.4,8142583.06666667,0
2.95779556035995E-02,7135615.73333333,8142516.56666667,0
6.0245580971241E-04,7135481.13333333,8142458.96666667,0
-3499.75561523438,1425869.76666667,8142458.1,0
-2799.95336914063,2491207,8142467.83333333,0
-2100.13159179688,3598205.9,8142531.33333333,0
-1400.34716796875,4744452.16666667,8142564.43333333,0
-699.84033203125,5926634.1,8142622,0
1.41168404370546E-02,7135535.46666667,8142676.03333333,0
699.789306640625,8362908.1,8142657.2,0
1400.41955566406,9600406.4,8142689.8,0
2100.16333007813,10834801.6666667,8142687.6,0
2799.95581054688,12058939.7,8142625.83333333,0
3499.76977539063,13265575.1,8142587.63333333,0
2100.11010742188,10834801.6333333,8142513.4,0
699.760375976563,8362953,8142452,0
-699.815490722656,5926588.76666667,8142387.16666667,0
-2100.15576171875,3598124.83333333,8142304.6,0
-3499.77612304688,1425477.66666667,8142238.9,0
1.88514944165945E-02,7135325.96666667,8142174.66666667,0
0.01649852655828,7135405.9,8142137.4,0
-4.3846950866282E-03,7135382.13333333,8142088.63333333,0
-1.14312199875712E-02,7135431.9,8142108.23333333,0
-4.01271730661392E-02,7135286.06666667,8142081.6,0
4.51517812907696E-02,7135541.73333333,8142075.76666667,0
2.85129714757204E-02,7135410.1,8142138.03333333,0
0.006099758669734,7135470.46666667,8142165.3,0
1.02824606001377E-02,7134510.53333333,8132538.73333333,0
-2.0309251267463E-03,7131902.96666667,8108401.86666667,0
2.09176428616047E-02,7128429.8,8078909.3,0
-4.88846525549889E-02,7124728.23333333,8050414.2,0
9.68774256762117E-04,7121720.06666667,8025573.8,0
1.36344395577908E-02,7119039.66666667,8005253.6,0
1.07799442484975E-02,7116918.86666667,7988969.83333333,0
-1.22267631813884E-02,7115146.06666667,7976052.53333333,0
1.52191026136279E-02,7113903.8,7965842.96666667,0
-2.48756278306246E-02,7112695.5,7957889.83333333,0
-1.06162242591381E-02,7111895.56666667,7951755.96666667,0
-1.45216090604663E-02,7111213.86666667,7947399.63333333,0
-2.66577322036028E-02,7110733.06666667,7944315.56666667,0
9.33546398300678E-04,7110476.93333333,7942078.73333333,0
-2.09947116672993E-02,7110238.73333333,7940342.13333333,0
-3.88443656265736E-02,7109937.8,7938704.8,0
3.89803200960159E-02,7109920.53333333,7937410.83333333,0
1.33107425644994E-02,7109717.6,7936618.03333333,0
3.34281765390188E-04,7109606.4,7936202.56666667,0
-5.09452447295189E-02,7109490.13333333,7936089.73333333,0
2.59053613990545E-02,7109693.8,7936036.13333333,0
5.85916265845299E-02,7109758.53333333,7935821.9,0
9.43354889750481E-03,7109565.9,7935476.16666667,0
0.011418279260397,7109456.8,7935225.1,0
-5.88321499526501E-03,7109472.8,7935093.23333333,0
-2.02441923320293E-02,7109351.3,7935176.26666667,0
-2.41300072520971E-02,7109365.96666667,7935323.96666667,0
5.2553890272975E-03,7109484.83333333,7935497.73333333,0
-1.75673943012953E-02,7109465.06666667,7935474.06666667,0
-5.93241788446903E-02,7109337.06666667,7935293.5,0
3.71915078721941E-03,7109429.93333333,7935136,0
1.06351356953382E-02,7109444.76666667,7935094.66666667,0
-0.040563065558672,7109235.1,7935166.96666667,0
-3.11746001243591E-02,7109487.96666667,7935387.56666667,0
-8.15856456756592E-02,7109371.16666667,7935601.16666667,0
-1.21781807392836E-02,7109510.86666667,7935603.43333333,0
-1.32531290873885E-02,7109431.93333333,7935415,0
-3499.84399414063,1203117.56666667,7935305.66666667,0
-2799.91088867188,2305275.4,7935271.63333333,0
-2100.1162109375,3450292.66666667,7935299.4,0
-1400.34167480469,4635995.2,7935352.1,0
-699.805419921875,5859010.06666667,7935378.1,0
-8.10023956000805E-03,7109360.8,7935475.9,0
699.84423828125,8379023.33333333,7935498.73333333,0
1400.29040527344,9658355.86666667,7935567.83333333,0
2100.146484375,10934762.3666667,7935684.73333333,0
2799.95581054688,12200104.9,7935743.7,0
3499.7783203125,13447040.8,7935825.33333333,0
2100.1796875,10934636.2333333,7935894.53333333,0
699.794372558594,8378867.83333333,7935990,0
-699.801940917969,5859394.56666667,7935990.26666667,0
-2100.15161132813,3451070.1,7935992.7,0
-3499.77319335938,1204084.1,7935981.46666667,0
9.18023637495935E-04,7109362.63333333,7935944.23333333,0
-4.76761683821678E-02,7109374.7,7935834.56666667,0
-0.030737467110157,7109448.16666667,7935805.56666667,0
4.49777618050575E-02,7109478.7,7935678.73333333,0
8.50645173341036E-03,7109433.46666667,7935668.63333333,0
0.019097026437521,7109456.8,7935566.9,0
-1.60152022726834E-03,7109385.53333333,7935556.43333333,0
3.06411702185869E-02,7109504.26666667,7935489.5,0
3499.76123046875,13447402.8666667,7935538.43333333,0
3499.79418945313,13447368.4333333,7935557.1,0
3499.740234375,13447198.7,7935563.46666667,0
3499.75415039063,13447247,7935589.4,0
3499.74682617188,13447236.2,7935591.8,0
-3499.7880859375,1203555.3,7935625.8,0
-3499.83813476563,1203285.6,7935726.23333333,0
-3499.81005859375,1203411.66666667,7935760.26666667,0
-3499.77783203125,1203464.8,7935861.33333333,0
-3499.81323242188,1203469.26666667,7935891.83333333,0
-3499.75219726563,1203670.63333333,7935907.53333333,0
-3499.736328125,1203693.73333333,7935915.96666667,0
-3499.75512695313,1203720.7,7935978.8,0
-3499.74072265625,1203788.2,7936078.3,0
-3499.74536132813,1203864.16666667,7936108.96666667,0
-3499.79760742188,1203808.1,7936129.83333333,0
-3499.79736328125,1203925.53333333,7936095.6,0
-3499.70556640625,1203868.8,7936092,0
-3499.74462890625,1203924.66666667,7936069.03333333,0
-3499.7607421875,1203752.63333333,7936098.43333333,0
-3499.77465820313,1203778.43333333,7936065,0
-3499.8017578125,1203646.8,7936028.36666667,0
-3499.77734375,1203654.06666667,7936027.76666667,0
-3499.80346679688,1203508.76666667,7935972.5,0
```

Comment: It would help others help you if you show exactly what errors you're bumping into. As a general comment, polynomial regression is known to be poorly conditioned (i.e. susceptible to small changes) for high-order polynomials; what, exactly, is the maximum degree you are trying? Can you work with low-order polynomials, let's say degree 2 or 3?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reduce the degree of the regression due to come extraneous constraints. The regression uses terms all the way up to the fourth degree.

Comment: You could try to implement some kind of fraction class with integer numerators and denominators instead of floats, which would preserve the exact value of the number (for rational values at least), but you'd either have to find or write that yourself which could be difficult

Comment: @NEPTTUNE do you think that would be doable with the built-in fractions class?

Comment: Javery, thanks for posting the data. What I see is that two of the columns have magnitudes which are much larger than the other one (the fourth column appears to be all zeros). My advice is to normalize all the nonzero columns to (value - mean)/s.d. (or any other reasonable normalization, the goal is just to make the magnitudes comparable). I suspect normalization will help a lot -- try the same analysis you are already doing and see if it works. FWIW fourth degree is not very high, should be okay.

Comment: you mention a 24 bit ADC, but these are all floats, how and why is the ADC output converted to floats?

Comment: @OMO2220 I'm not sure, but you bring up a good observation. I am not the one actually collecting this data, but that's what I was told. Perhaps there were actually more bits than that, or there were some extra steps done before this data got to me.

Comment: @RobertDodier In my code, I am normalizing those two columns by dividing by 2^24 already. This brings those two columns into the domain of [-1,1].

Comment: Javery, thanks for pointing out the normalization, that's great. I'm looking at scatterplots of the first three columns, and first column vs. second column is nearly linear, but first column vs. third, and second column vs. third, look strange. If the third column is a measurement from a controlled experiment, then grid-like measurements make sense, but then I would expect one or the other of the other columns to be a response variable, and scattered around. I guess P and T are pressure and temperature? What is b in that case? Hope this helps.

Comment: The first column, that I called b for convenience, is the response variable, and columns 2 and 3 are the independent variables, Pressure and Temperature respectively. This is a controlled experiment, yes, so both the 2nd and 3rd columns are intentionally like that.

Comment: @javery I think so, because from what I can tell (from documentation and a tiny bit of testing) the fraction class stores the numerator and denominator as ints which would allow for potentially unlimited precision. I say potentially because after around python 3.11, integers are only unlimited if you call `sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)`, ideally near or at the start of the program. As an extra note I'm not sure how using fractions would handle being normalised - it might work fine since it should work exactly the same as using a float, but it might go really weird - testing would be required

Answer (score 2):

There are generally 2 approaches to preventing floating point errors:

1. Using integers/fractional representation (a/b) and only converting to float in the last step when all of the additions, subtractions, multiplications, etc have been carried out. Since you're using a 24-bit ADC, I suspect this will be the best approach: Read your 24-bit data into a larger buffer (for example 64 bits, but be careful if they're signed values as you'll need some bit shifting to prevent messing up the sign). Run your regression using integers only and only when trying to display the values to the user use floats
2. If you must convert to float and use floats, the only real options are to either use double instead of float (since you're not memory-constrained this should be an easy test) or to sort the floats before you add, multiply, divide etc. You can also look into Kahan Summation algorithm which is a more efficient way of doing the same thing but you said performance isn't an issue. I haven't tried benchmarking sorting vs Kahan, but from previous experiences they'll be very similar.

Like others mentioned, posting your data (since you say it's small and ~400 rows should be fine to post it raw here) and your code which has reproducible errors, it would be a lot easier to recommend a proper fix or solution.

Comment: Python's float is really a double (`np.dtype(float)` is `dtype('float64')`). OP could do `dtype=np.clongdouble` or `dtype=np.float128`. Not sure what that does to performance.

Comment: @tdelaney I actually tried using `dtype=np.float128` and it had no effect, despite the docs saying otherwise. When I'd load the data using that kwarg, running `type()` on the elements just returned `float64`.

Comment: @javery - when you pull a single element from the array, numpy converts it to a python data type. So you get a python `float`. Assuming an array called "arr", you could do `arr.dtype.itemsize` to see how many bytes it consumes. Your float128 should be 16 while a float is 8. You may find `np.clongfloat` is a better option. There are several implementations of these longer floats but I think that letting the compiler select its native type is best.

Comment: @tdelaney Using `dtype=np.clongdouble` did give me 16 when I ran `arr.dtype.itemsize`, but I'm not sure that fixes the problem, as I don't have any imaginary components. When I ran `arr.dtype.itemsize` using `np.float128`, it still gives me 8.

Comment: @javery - Interesting. My clongdouble is 32, float128 is 16 and float is 8. numpy version 1.25.2.